# my url's in the menu in header.jsp not working as I have restricted direct access by putting all my jsp's in web-inf

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

header.jsp:

I'm using filter in my application and all the jsp are in WEB-INF folder. and when ever I click on the button it gives me 404 error. Before that all the jsp's where out side the WEB-INF folder it was working fine. But i was able to access with out logging in. I placed all the jsp pages in the WEB-INF. I think url is not right or something but please go through the code,  and help me.

```
 <form name="headerform" action="Get">
     <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${usertype eq 'Employee'}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>

            <li class="current"><a href="/WEB-INF/daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${usertype eq 'Manager'}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="/WEB-INF/daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${usertype eq 'Admin'}">
         <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="/WEB-INF/daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="/WEB-INF/daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </form>
```